# How to disable certain Nuxt 3 pages?

Tags: nuxtjs3, feature-flags

Sometimes you have **unfinished pages** you **don't want to make publicly available yet** but you still want to publish the rest of your work.

You can either strictly work with **feature branches**, or you **rename your page file ending** into something like .txt, or you **move them out of the pages directory**.

**Is it somehow possible to disable certain pages of your Nuxt 3 app?**

Comment: Git you need to use git.

Comment: @Mises thanks, I'm doing that already. But love to hear your opinion: people came to the conclusion that Gitflow should be ditched in favor of trunk based development, which is heavily using feature flags. Let's say I use that, what should I do now with unfinished pages?

Answer (score 3):

you can add this settings file

nuxt.config.ts

```
  ignore:  [
        'components/web/**/*',
        'pages/auth/**/*',
        'pages/home/**/*',
        'pages/settings/**/*',
      ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the `.nuxtignore` file?

```bash
# ignore layout foo.vue
layouts/foo.vue
# ignore layout files whose name ends with -ignore.vue
layouts/*-ignore.vue
# ignore page bar.vue
pages/bar.vue
# ignore page inside ignore folder
pages/ignore/*.vue
# ignore route middleware files under foo folder except foo/bar.js
middleware/foo/*.js
!middleware/foo/bar.js
```

https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/nuxtignore#nuxt-ignore-file

This seems to fit what you're trying to achieve.